Why can the Lagrangian Multiplier be dropped in the inverse demand function?
I'm deriving the Antras and Helpman (2004) paper. The model assumes a nested CES utility function
$$
U = x_0 + \frac{1}{\mu} \sum_{j=1}^{J} X_j^\mu
$$
where $X_j = \left[ \int x_j(i)^\alpha \,di \right]^{1/\alpha}$.
The paper straightforwardly shows that the inverse demand function for each variety i in sector j is
$$
p_j(i) = X^{\mu-\alpha}x_j(i)^{\alpha-1}
$$
I know this can be obtained by setting up the Lagrangian function and finding the first-order condition with respect to $x_j(i)$. But why here we can drop the Lagrangian multiplier $\lambda$? What I actually found is
$$
p_j(i) = X^{\mu-\alpha}x_j(i)^{\alpha-1} (1/\lambda)
$$
I suspect in this case we can normalise $\lambda$ to 1 due to some implicit assumption that is not clearly stated in the paper. But I never heard that we could easily drop or normalise the Lagrangian multiplier in any of my previous economics and maths class.

Does price/inverse demand have a specified unit, e.g. is $x_0$ a numeraire good? If not, you could normalize the price unit in such a way that $\lambda$ becomes one.

@Giskard Yes, $x_0$ is a numeraire good. Then why do we have $\lambda$ to be one when we have the numeraire good?

I don't know, I wrote a suggestion that works if it was not a numeraire.

The Lagrangian is given by:
$$
L = x_0 + \frac{1}{\mu} \sum_{j = 1}^J X_j^\mu - \lambda(x_0 + \sum_j \int_i p_j(i) x_j(i) di - m).
$$
The first order condition (for an interior solution) with respect to $x_0$ gives:
$$
1 - \lambda = 0
$$
So $\lambda = 1$.
